# Try to understand Applicative in Haskell

Tags: haskell

```
class Functor f where
    fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b

class (Functor f) => Applicative f where
    pure a = f a
    <*> :: f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

I try to understand **Applicative** in Haskell
From the definition of **Applicative**, it looks like the subclass of **Functor**

I assume fmap is like an interface for Functor (in Java world)
If **Applicative** subclasses from Functor then it needs implement fmap from Functor, but fmap in **Functor** and **Applicative** are different in signature

```
(a -> b) -> f a -> f b
f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

Can anyone explain why?

Comment: This is simply wrong. `fmap` is not defined in the applicative typeclass.

Comment: the second signature you're showing is for the [`(<*>)` method](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-60--42--62-) from the Applicative typeclass. not for `fmap`.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, as @paul mentioned, the definitions you're working from are a bit off. The correct definitions would be the following:

```
class Functor f where
    fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b

class Functor f => Applicative f where
    pure :: a -> f a
    (<*>) :: f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

So how should these definitions be decoded? The main thing to realise here is that Haskell typeclasses have more in common with Java interfaces than Java classes - so the `Applicative` definition here is not defining a subclass in the Java sense, but specifying that a type can only be an instance of `Applicative` if it is already an instance of `Functor` (i.e. all `Applicative`s must also implement `fmap`, even though it is not part of the `Applicative` typeclass). For more info on `Functor` and `Applicative`, I can highly recommend the online book [Learn You a Haskell for Great Good](http://learnyouahaskell.com/), particularly the [section on 'Functors, Applicative and Monoid'](http://learnyouahaskell.com/functors-applicative-functors-and-monoids).

Answer (score 3):

Please refers the document of [Control.Applicative](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#t:Applicative). The type signature of

```
(<*>) :: f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

is sequential application operator `<*>` not `fmap`.

> I assume fmap is like an interface for Functor (in Java world) If
>   Applicative subclasses from Functor then it needs implement fmap from
>   Functor

Actually, `Applicative` is also like an interface in Java world, more exact, like an interface with [default methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html) introduced since Java 8. In Java syntax like:

```
public interface Applicative extends Functor {..}
```

Notes that the definition of `Applicative` in Java here is not a concrete class, it need **not** to implement `fmap` from `Functor` interface.

Answer (score 2):

I think the definitions you're working with are a little off (maybe the source is wrong, or maybe you misinterpreted them) and that's the source of your confusion.

As @AJFarmar mentions in the comments, `fmap` is part of the `Functor` typeclass (or Interface in Java terms); the definition of `Applicative` says that whenever you try to make an `Applicative` instance (i.e. implement the `Applicative` interface) then the type you're trying to make the instance for *also* has to be an instance of `Functor` (it also has to implement the `Functor` interface). So the signature of `fmap` will always be:

```
fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```